# Bash Exit Issue

Tags: bash, shell

The current script (`scan.sh`) is taking too much time to negotiate with any one of the listed cipher below and process is stuck at that point trying to negotiate.

```
$ openssl ciphers -V | grep "CBC3"

          0xC0,0x12 - ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
          0xC0,0x08 - ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
          0x00,0x16 - EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
          0x00,0x13 - EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
          0xC0,0x0D - ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
          0xC0,0x03 - ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
          0x00,0x0A - DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Run Command :

$./scan.sh X.X.X.X

How do i exit for the any of the delaying cipher and move to the next cipher for negotiation ? Any suggestions please , I'm not familiar in Bash.

```
#scan.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

# OpenSSL requires the port number.
SERVER=$1:443
DELAY=1
ciphers=$(openssl ciphers -V | grep "CBC3" | awk '{print $3}')

for cipher in ${ciphers[@]}
do
echo -n Testing $cipher...
result=$(echo -n | openssl s_client -cipher "$cipher" -connect $SERVER 2>&1)
if [[ "$result" =~ ":error:" ]] ; then
  error=$(echo -n $result | cut -d':' -f6)
  echo NO \($error\)
else
  if [[ "$result" =~ "Cipher is ${cipher}" || "$result" =~ "Cipher    :" ]] ; then
    echo YES
  else
    echo UNKNOWN RESPONSE
    echo $result
  fi
fi
sleep $DELAY
done
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#timeout-invocation) command?  It's in GNU CoreUtils, rather than Bash per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you could make `ciphers` an array like below for a neater look?

```
ciphers=( $(openssl ciphers -V | awk '/CBC3/{print $3}') )
```

then  do something like

```
result="$(timeout 10s openssl s_client -cipher "${cipher[@]" -connect "$SERVER" 2>&1)"
```

**Notes**

- `timeout 10s` waits 10s for the command to finish else kills it
- Double quote the variables like `"$SERVER"` and make script variables lower case so that it won't conflict with system variables.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : Nice point  about `2>&1` but regarding `echo -n`, which looks unnecessary here, why should the op include it here?

Comment: @sjsam Thank you. timeout function really helps here. Regarding "echo -n " ,Yes i have mentioned it unnecessarily ! have removed it on my original run.

Comment: That's a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) - anything which looks like `grep x | awk '{foo}'` can usefully be refactored to `awk '/x/{foo}'`

Comment: @tripleee : Didn't notice that indeed, updated. Thankyou.